# Git Submodule URL change for existing commits in the server side

Tags: git

The command "git config submodule.common.url 'url'" is only useful to client side submodule url change. I want to change submodule url on the server side and it should support all previous commits in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is with `filter-branch` or `rebase -i` with edit. All your SHA1s will change though.